Подскажите как и где, без привязки к конкретному ЯП или на С/С++, изучить web- технологию!
Не встречал ещё, чтобы описывалась web-технология без привязки к конкретному ЯП. Дело в том, что все движутся по протоптанной дорожке, изучая её, с привязкой с PHP, JS, HTML, CSS и т.д. Эти ЯП и псевдоЯП "заточены" под web, где это всё и рассматривается, но базируются они(их библиотеки, фреймворк и т.п.), в большинстве, на С/С++, в котором эта технология не рассматривается. Специально изучать такие "тормоза", как PHP, JS и др. не хочется. Как компромис пока есть Go, но зачем он мне, если я предпочитаю С/С++! Посоветуйте как быть?

Эм-м-м... Веб делится на две части: фронтенд и бэкенд. Фронтенд - это HTML, CSS, JavaScript. Учите их. Вместо JS можете учить TypeScript. Хотите бэкенд писать на C/C++ - хорошо, вам никто не запрещает, учите эти языки. Осталось связать эти части. Для этого учите технологии, по которым гоняются данные и форматы данных: HTTP, REST, GraphQL, WebSocket, SSE, Protobuf, JSON... Ну и про базы данных не забудьте...

@AlexanderPetrov, а фронтенд нельзя что ли сделать на С/С++? А бэкенд разве рассматривается где-то на С/С++? Знаю есть немало фреймворков на С/С++ для создания web-приложений, но не встречалось описание, как это делать.

Ох... (Спокойствие, только спокойствие!) Браузеры не умеют исполнять нативный код, только JS (ну, почти). Однако, смотрите в сторону WebAssembly - эта технология позволяет делать фронтенд практически на любом языке.

"изучать XXX не хочется. ...но я предпочитаю С/С++"  --- тогда стОит рассмотреть те направления, под которые они подходят наиболее всего. Связанное с вебом может быть - ну например разработка браузера или его инструментов. Изготовление ПО для, не знаю, анализа траффика сети.... Если имеется web-технология в том смысле, в котором оно применяется сейчас  - то "С" явно не лучший кандидат....... Это всё равно что говорить: резать масло обычным ножом я не буду, мне он не интересен, я предпочитаю тесак. Или: ехать на работу 2 станции метро - фу, не буду, я предпочитаю самолёт!

Любой ЯП это всего лишь инструмент и должен быть оптимально подобран под задачу. Лопатой можно выкопать котлован, но ведь экскаватор лучше с этим справляется.

Уважаемые, конечно, всё зависит от сформулированных критериев и их расставленных приоритетах, а потому и используются разные инструменты. Для высоконагруженных сайтов и общественных сервисов, PHP и ему подобные не подойдут, если не параллерить и выстраивать этажи из серверов, как у некоторых соцсетей, вроде, Facebook, кажется. Google, вроде, на ANSI C накодили!

Не льстите себе... В большей своей массе, такие "актуальные и интересные" вопросы привлекают внимания не из-за актуальности, а из-за интереса почитать комментарии, не более. Как и сейчас )

Возьмём гоночный автомобиль Формулы 1 - быстрый, шо пипец! Выезжаем на нём на грунтовую дорогу и мгновенно застреваем... Ну и где скорость? А что если нужно семью возить: муж, жена и двое детей. Ф1 с этим не справится. А что если 10 тонн цемента нужно перевезти? Камаз как-то эффективнее будет, не? Понимаете, для каждого вида работы выгоднее свой инструмент.

Изучают именно в таком порядке не просто так.
Как уже сказали, веб-технологии делятся на две части, это фронтэнд и бекэнд.
Фронтэнд
На стороне фронтэнда находится пользователь и его компьютер. Для отображения информации используется браузер, который отвечает требованиям безопасности. Его задача отрисовать страницу и показать её пользователю.
Тут вас ждет первое разочарование, вы можете пользоваться только тем, что может браузер и ограничены его возможностями. А задача браузера получить текстовое описание документа в HTML и никак иначе, по этому описанию он сам построит страницу. Отображение компонентов в браузере настраивается через CSS, других способов браузер не поддерживает. Ну и в догонку для программного управления находящимся на странице элементами используется встраиваемый язык JavaScript.
С этой стороны браузер уже вас ограничиваем набором технологий, которые вы можете использовать внутри него. Есть конечно WebAssembly, но это будет усложнение ради усложнения.
Бекэнд
Задача бекэнда отдать просто данные для браузера, тут вы можете использовать всё, что захотите. Браузеру нужно отдать его начальные HTML/CSS/JS (с нужными метаданными в виде заголовков) и дальше просто перекидываться данными.
Но и тут не всё так просто, поскольку придется писать свой веб-сервер для обработки данных. Но такие сервера уже написаны, при этом на Си и большой толпой квалифицированных разработчиков. Вы даже можете использовать их наработки для себя или покопаться в их исходниках. Вот, для примера, статья на тему Разработка веб приложений на C/С++ [nginx + fastcgi] + Web-приложение на C/C++ с помощью FastCGI — это просто.
Но в вебе в первую очередь преимущество имеют наличие готовых инструментов, скорость разработки, удобства разработки и внесения изменений. И тут этим похвастаться С/С++ не могут. Скорость работы и оптимизация это хорошо, но современный мир требует готовое приложение здесь и сейчас.
Клиент-серверные приложения
Но если отбросить браузер как клиентскую часть фронтэнда, диктующую основные условия, и написать свой клиент - то вы получите обычное клиент-серверное приложение. А как разрабатывать клиент-серверные приложения материалов значительно больше. Веб-технология это просто частный случай, поэтому в теории вы можете ограничиться этим как изучением без привязки к языку.
UPD
Браузер рендерит внутри себя HTML+CSS, от них вы не уйдете никуда, браузер понимает только их. Далее браузер выставляет наружу интерфейсы, обращение к которым управляет поведением страницы. К этим интерфейсам можно обращаться через JavaScript и добавлять функциональность через WebAssembly (написать программу на С/С++ и скомпилировать в WebAssembly).
При этом сам WebAssembly позиционируется как возможность работать совместно с JavaScript и его код вы все равно встретите. Накидаю несколько примеров:

На MDN есть примеры использования и как это работает: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/WebAssembly
Туториал к Emscripten: https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html
Статья на хабре по теме: https://habr.com/ru/articles/718874/

Опять же всё сводится к тому, что придется все равно изучить, как работать правильно в окружении браузера, который диктует условия. Изучить их проще по пути HTML+CSS+JS. Да, вы можете использовать С/С++ для ускорения сложных вычислений, но в большинстве случаев этого не требуется. Код писать для этих целей сложнее, а JS давно обзавелся зоопарком библиотек.
Итого да, в какой-то степени можно и на фронте использовать С/С++, но довольно затруднительно и невыгодно для большинства сценариев.

Спасибо! Вы наиболее полно раскрыли тему заданного вопроса! Только я не до конца понял почему на С/С++ нельзя сделать фронтенд? Возможно, точнее сказать - можно, но крайне затруднительно и не выгодно!?

@Reason фронтэнд выполняется браузером. Браузер в простом случае поддерживает html + css + js. В более сложном - можно использовать технологию webassembly (где можно использовать компилируемые языки), но это в целом относительно сложно, для большинства сайтов это не нужно.

@Reason, дополнил ответ описанием для фронта, со ссылками на источники, как это делается. А так ответ да - затруднительно и невыгодно, условия тут диктуют браузеры, фронт работает внутри их окружения.

@Alex Krass, дополнительно Большое Спасибо! Заглядывайте на мои вопросы, ибо я люблю задавать непростые, интересные вопросы, только не каждый может их грамотно оценить, а, порой, не зная ответа из-за требований нестандартного подхода, до конца не понимая, в силу своей ограниченности мышления, назло "опускают" рейтинг вопроса! Надеюсь, вы и другие не допустите этого!

@Reason, да просто следует немного привыкнуть к сайту и его правилам. На платформе Stack Exchange много форумов, это только один из них, платформа позволяет просто так поставить минус - практически это не на что не влияет, важнее взаимоуважение и вежливость. Вопросы-обсуждения в большинстве случаев закрываются, но все тут обычные люди, часть которых любят слететься и пообщаться под такими вопросами. В общем я ожидал, что и этот вопрос могут спокойно закрыть по правилам как возможно дискуссионный, если не переписать его на точный вопрос-ответ формат.

Поскольку вопрос закрыт и нет возможности ответить отдельно, то для ещё большей полноты ответа решил добавить ссылку, где алгоритмически на рисунках  воспроизведены web-технологии без- и с привязкой к специализированным под web ЯП: https://svyatoslav.biz/education/webtechs_and_webapps_in_pictures/

"Веб-технологии" в основе своей имеют HTML. Дополнительный необходимый минимум - CSS и JS.
Поэтому без изучения этих неЯП (с некоторой оговоркой разве что js можно отнести к таковым) изучение веб-технологий не мыслимо.
ЯП же всего-то и делают, что в результате работы "программы" формируют html (а также могут и остальное). И тут почти не важно какой именно ЯП это будет делать.  Другое дело что web-сервер должен уметь с ними работать. А тут уже не всё так просто. Поэтому основными ЯП на сегодня являются PHP, Python и Perl.
Но кроме ЯП в "веб-технологиях" применяется масса других ...эмм... "технологий" - от SQL до администрирования серверов.

вы сделали, похоже, опечатку в ЯП Python. Поясните, пожалуйста, к примеру, PHP является базовым ЯП для web, однако, думаю, все его библиотеки сделаны на С/С++! Почему бы тогда не использовать для этих целей и сам С/С++?

Допустил опечатку, да . А насчёт "почему  php" - можно на костре есть готовить, но удобнее и эффективнее на печке. И уже вторично - газовой или электрической.  Остальное всё есть в интернете. Умение пользоваться поисковыми системами - необходимый базовый навык любого разработчика. И да, когда найдёшь сервер, который сможет понять твои кресты и выдать html - никто не запретит тебе и на крестах писать.

@Reason полезно продолжить вашу аргументацию для выяснения её ложности. Можно писать все на Ассемблере, ведь на нем все написано по сути. Или на машинных кодах. А еще лучше на железе без софта сразу все реализовывать, тогда и это будет не нужно )

@Kromster, слишком утрируете и не берёте во внимание переносимость и жёсткую "привязанность" к конкретному "железу", поэтому то и был выбран компромиссный вариант! А, вообще, в зависимости от сайта и его необходимых характеристик и выбираются инструменты для его реализации, а не реализуют все подряд сайты по шаблону одними и теми же инструментами и "опускают" потом тех, кто думает иначе, с учётом критериев и их приоритетов и они у вас другие, причём по-умолчанию, о которых вы даже и не знаете!

@Reason да ты, поди, под каждые трусы отдельную стиральную машинку покупаешь? Инструменты он подбирает.. вообще понятия не имея как делаются и работают сайты. ЯП от разметки не отличает.. Ну да, все ж вокруг дураки (раз используют php и тп),  а он один умный... Тут либо жирный тролль либо клиника. А не порвётся ли твой шаблон, если узнаешь, что более половины сайтов в интернете вообще сделаны на одном движке? :)

@SeVlad, если бы я знал, как делаются сайты, то и не задавал бы этого вопроса, однако я не встречал, чтобы кто-то грамотно, подробно и доступно написал о web-технологии, без привязки к ЯП и объяснил когда и какой ЯП применять для конкретного сайта, исходя из требований на него! Замечу, что это, кроме меня понимают из ответивших Eugene Krivenja, Alexander Petrov.Почитайте! А вы, похоже, не можете или не хотите понять, что есть и другие критерии и приоритеты, кроме ваших! Короче, раз вы опытный и знаете, как делаются и работают сайты, то поделитесь знаниями и вам будут только благодарны за это!

@Reason Мало того что это всё давно разжевано, так тебе всё ещё и тут объяснили. Если ты не способен понять - это другой вопрос. Тогда иди траншеи копать. Думаю, не долго будешь спрашивать почему это лучше делать лопатами, а не железной рудной и стволами.

@SeVlad держите себя в руках пожалуйста. Даже если человек неисренне заблуждается, лучше ему толково рассказать (заодно и для себя лучше разложить по полочкам), а не скатываться в сторону оскорблений :-)

@Kromster.. ок, спасибо за замечание. Но... он явно троллит. Ну не может разработчик так "заблуждаться"...

@SeVlad люди и не ТАК заблуждаются. Однако, в таких заблуждениях может быть скрыто толковое зерно. Лет 60 назад думали, мол зачем кому-то может понадобиться домашний компьютер, ерунда какая, известно же что комп занимает комнату и нужен только большим организациям. Лет 30 назад, мол кому может придти в голову переносной ПК со своей ОС для звонков и смс. Слаботипизированные языки типа JS, централизованный выпуск денег, ИИ, и т.п. и т.д. Соответственно и рассуждения были примерно такими же - мол зачем оспаривать обще-известные вещи.

@Kromster тут "заблуждения" даже не в том, "зачем ПК, если есть счёты" (хотя и в этом тоже), тут гораздо страшнее - "зачем строить дом из кирпичей, если есть песок и глина" (в см. ингредиенты для производства кирпичей, а не стройматериал). А не понимать, что нет серверов, работающих напрямую с машинами кодами или даже крестами - это что, тоже "заблуждение"? Нет, я понимаю, когда  человек этого не знает. Но когда об этом написано тонны букв в интернетах, и даже тут несколько раз повторили - это уже не заблуждение и незнание. Это или упоротось или троллинг. Я уже молчу про игнор опыта поколений.

@SeVlad для прогресса, опыт поколений как-раз таки полезно регулярно испытывать и оспаривать. Всегда ездили на бензине, все заправки бензиновые, зачем вообще задаваться вопросом, может ли авто быть на батарейках )) Ну и обратно к теме, бэк и фронт на C++ вполне себе возможен, взять например любую ММОРПГ (у которой не сделали GUI через Хромиум).

@Kromster 1) чтобы оспаривать опыт поколений как минимум нужен этот самый опыт (личный) и немерено знаний. А иначе это просто ЧСВ, ничего более. 2)Web-cерверов, понимающих нативные кресты, насколько я знаю нет в природе. "Что-то" написанное на C++ проходит через "прокладки". 3) Можно долго ещё махать транспарантами прогресса, но в данном случае ТС и  слышать не хочет про html/css,. О каком написании чего-либо под веб можно говорить и оправдывать его? (при этом он хочет быть оторванным от ЯП в изучении технологий, но при этом писать на С++. Раздвоение личности или...?). Но давай заканчивать.

@SeVlad на HTML+CSS свет клином не сходится. Да, бытовой пользовательский рынок захвачен HTML+CSS+JS, однако, при наличии более широкого взгляда, можно увидеть немало альтернатив. Как уже упомянуто, многие онлайн игры можно рассматривать как пример альтернативы "Вебу". Многие мобильные приложения (в т.ч. Fb или Ig или Тг) - это тоже другой транспорт и презентация. Также, например, ничто не мешает сделать простой сайт на голом HTML+CSS генерируемых сервером на чистом C++. В общем вариантов не мало, просто их надо увидеть и проанализировать, а не просто так отметать как "ересь" :-)

У меня вот есть микро-сервер на Delphi - живет, работает, пользу приносит :-)

@Kromster,  бытовой рынок.. мобильные приложения... альтернативы "Вебу" (внезапно в веб-технологиях!)... кони, люди... блин. не о чем дальше говорить... но про веб технологии по русски: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web

@Kromster, спасибо за понимание, критическое осмысление и широту взгляда! Я с вами полностью согласен! SeVlad у нас с вами разные подходы к данному вопросу, отсюда и нет понимания, причём вы опытный кодер, но крайне консервативен и это плохо, поскольку именно это вам и мешает взглянуть на вопрос с другой стороны, и это типичная ошибка для большинства профи. Именно взгляд с другой стороны на проблему, нестандартный подход и движет прогресс, и даёт более глубокое понимание темы.

@SeVlad, Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1578194/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%af%d0%9f-%d0%a1-%d0%b8-%d0%a1?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C6.5134 и обратите внимание на статью там по моей ссылке и реакцию на неё опытного прогера и после всего этого хорошенько призадумайтесь. Надеюсь, после этого вы всё поймёте, в т.ч. и по данному вопросу!
